# How to set the background colour of a RadioButton?

Tags: android

Can you please tell me how to set the background colour of a RadioButton?
If user selects **yes**, the background color should change to green.
When user selects **no**, the background color should change to red.

here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/header" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:stretchColumns="2" >

        <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFF00" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Eligibility confirmed:" 
                android:layout_weight=".5"/>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/eligibility"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight=".5" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/eligibilityYes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="yes" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/eligibilityNo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="No" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:background="#FFFF00" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Informed consent given and explained:"
              android:layout_weight=".5"
               />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/explained"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" 
                android:layout_weight=".5">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/explainedYes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="yes" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/explainedNo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="No" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <!--
         <Button 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="ClickMe"/>
    -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why not using button.setBackgroundColor();

Comment: just used `button.setBackgroundColor();`

Comment: You still not accepted any answer. none of them helped you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try this way..
hope this is help you....

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/eligibility"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight=".5" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/eligibilityYes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
                android:text="yes" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/eligibilityNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
                android:text="No" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

your checkbox_background.xml file put image in res/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_rad" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_green" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 3):

android:button parameter of RadioButton.
Example-

```
 <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:button="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

radio_button_selector.xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_dark" android:state_checked="true" />

</selector>
```

On radiobutton checked listener if radio button is checked you can set radio button.setbackground(..)

Comment: add radio_button_selector.xml in drawable folder.

Answer (score 3):

try this...

```
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            if(radioButton.getText().equals("yes")) {
                radioButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                radioButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What if the user himself uses setOnCheckedChangeListener another place? eg for custom views that you don't have control over using this method elsewhere.

Comment: @EmiRaz Not sure I understood your question

Comment: You have declared an OnCheckedChangeListener for your view. what happens when you set OnCheckedChangeListener somewhere else. all you have set will be overridden. this issue occurs when you try to create a custom view for RadioGroup and expect that the background color works fine, but it may not.