# How to set background color of radiobuttons if it matches with the text of edittext?

Tags: android, radio-button

Inside radio group, I have 4 radio buttons.
I have 4 edit text also.

So if the user writes "yes" in  edit text 1 I want to change the background color of the radio button 1 to green.Initially, all are in the white background.
No button press required.

By default edit text 1 will have "Yes" in it.

```
    Radiobutton 1  > edittext 1 
    Radiobutton 2  > edittext 2
    Radiobutton 3  > edittext 3
    Radiobutton 4  > edittext 4



    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.answers);
    rg.clearCheck();

    rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a0);
    rb1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a1);
    rb2.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a2);
    rb3.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    rb4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a3);
    rb4.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);


    addListenerOnButton();

}

   private void addListenerOnButton() {


    if (etv1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        rb1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        rb2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        rb3.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        rb4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else if (etv2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        rb2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        rb1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        rb3.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        rb4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else if (etv3.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        rb3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        rb2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        rb1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        rb4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else if (etv4.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        rb4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        rb2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        rb3.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        rb1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the next code:

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/eligibility"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight=".5" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/eligibilityYes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
                android:text="yes" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/eligibilityNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background"
                android:text="No" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

You have the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601704/how-to-set-the-background-colour-of-a-radiobutton).

Comment: I am fetching the text on radio button from Url(JSON parsing).So no point on changing the text of radio button.I want to match the edittext values and change the color@Sermanes